# Почему не работает By.PartialLinkText? Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

Суть вопроса: Необходимо определить, появляется ли сообщение на странице через 3 секунды после старта теста. Использую код ниже, но почему-то не получается определить элемент по PartialLinkText, хотя если вместо него использовать By.ClassName, всё успешно проходит. В errorMessage передаю сообщение, которое должно появиться (The Login field is required).

```
string temp = new WebDriverWait(Properties.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.PartialLinkText(errorMessage))).Text;
```

Comment: Добавьте html-код ссылки

Comment: Вопрос решился путём использования Xpath